# Annotation Sub Class custom initWithCoordinate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkannotation

I've subclassed MKAnnotation so that i can assign objects to each annotation, this is so that when the rightCalloutAccessoryView is clicked i can push a navigation controller with the object passed to it and display the objects data in another view.

This all works great apart from one thing, i've extended upon initWithCoordinate like so:

```
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord andObject:(NSManagedObject *)object {

    [self setPlace:object];

    coordinate = coord;
    title = [place valueForKey:@"name"];
    subtitle = [place valueForKey:@"address"];

    return self;

}
```

Although everything is working great i'm recieving the warning:

```
NO '-initWithCoordinate:andObject:' method found
```

Which means i'm doing something wrong somewhere, what is the correct way to go about adding upon initWithCoorinate?

Comment: are you declaring it in your .h? i can't think of why else that particular error would be thrown.

Comment: gah yup being an idiot, i pasted it into the a .h file of another project i had open, friday afternoon slow brain :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the prototype `-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord andObject:(NSManagedObject *)object` in .h file.